# Mockito: Detect when a method on a private resource is invoked

Tags: java, mockito

I need to write a test for this class. I need to verify that when the size of the list is exactly 2 then the modelService.save is called. Is it also possible to get to the object productModel?

I don't know where to start.

```
public class SoldMaterialPrepareInterceptor implements PrepareInterceptor<SoldMaterialModel> {

    @Resource
    private ModelService modelService;

    @Override
    public void onPrepare(SoldMaterialModel soldMaterialModel, InterceptorContext interceptorContext) throws InterceptorException {
            setSAPSubstance(soldMaterialModel);
    }

    private void setSAPSubstance(SoldMaterialModel soldMaterialModel) {
        ProductModel productModel = soldMaterialModel.getBaseProduct();
        Set superCatagoriesList = [....]// gets the list somehow
        if (superCatagoriesList.size() == 2) {
            productModel.setSupercategories(superCatagoriesList);
            modelService.save(productModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem that the modelService field is private, it is a class field for which private access modifier is usually expected. You need to check the invocation of its save() method, which in turn cannot be private, otherwise it would not be possible to call it from the interceptor class.

As for the test, assuming the superCatagoriesList (which is actually a Set and not a List and also should be generic) gets its content directly or indirectly (e.g. through productModel) from the soldMaterialModel parameter, your task is to write a test, which populates soldMaterialModel with such values so that superCatagoriesList.size() will be 2, and then you can verify that the modelService.save() method was called exactly once with e.g. something like

```
Mockito.verify(modelService).save(any(ProductModel.class));
```

Comment: @Test
    public void setSAPSubstance() throws Exception {

        soldMaterialPrepareInterceptor.onPrepare(soldMaterial, interceptorContext);
        Mockito.verify(modelService).save(any(ProductModel.class));
        assert (false);
    }

This is what I have, but I get an error on your suggested line of code.

Comment: I have mocked the 2 parameters and resource modelservice

Answer (score 1):

I found that when it is difficult to test a method most often there is a design problem of the code I am testing. I suggest a minor to refactoring first: move setSAPSubstance to SoldMaterialModel class and make it public. That is where that method needs to be (see [feature envy](http://wiki.c2.com/?FeatureEnvySmell)). Of course `modelService.save(productModel);` will stay in the interceptor and it will be called only if needed.
Then you will only have to test the two public methods

Answer (score 1):

Is that the whole class? Then I think I see the issue. There are no non-private ways to set the ModelService. When the whole app runs, the dependency injection framework uses reflection to set the ModelService. When you run the test, you don't have anyway to inject a mock. You have a few options.

You can add a constructor to SoldMaterialPrepareInterceptor which takes the ModelService as a parameter. Then you can use that in your test. You would probably also have to add a no-argument constructor because that's how your dependency injection framework creates it. Better yet, you could figure out how to configure the framework to use the new constructor that takes the ModelService.

```
public class SoldMaterialPrepareInterceptor {
    // Public constructor if needed for dependency injection
    public SoldMaterialPrepareInterceptor () { }

    // If just used for test use protected or package private
    // If used with dependency injection, use public.
    protected SoldMaterialPrepareInterceptor(ModelService modelService){
        this.modelService = modelService
    }
```

The test class is usually in the same package as the actual class, so package private or protected scope is enough. Then the test looks something like this (Assuming Mockito and Junit. Logically, Spock and other frameworks would be similar):

```
ModelService modelService = Mockito.mock(ModelService.class);
SoldMaterialPrepareInterceptor interceptor = new SoldMaterialPrepareInterceptor(modelService);
// setup SoldMaterialModel and InterceptorContext
interceptor.onPrepare(soldMaterialModel, interceptorContext);
Mockito.verify(modelService, Mockito.times(0)).save(soldMaterialModel);
```